# Exit browser full screen mode when F11 is hit while Flash object is active?

Tags: javascript, flash, browser, fullscreen

I have a 100% width and height flash object in my site. Activating and exiting browser full screen mode with <kbd>F11</kbd> only works as long the user didn't click the Flash movie. And I doubt many users know they have to click the address bar to enable <kbd>F11</kbd> after using a (browser) full screen Flash movie.

Is there any way I can enable <kbd>F11</kbd> to work if the Flash object is active?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for security reasons Adobe disable all keyboard events while in full-screen mode, you still have full mouse events, but the only key that can change the full-screen mode back to windowed mode is the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

When switching to full-screen mode a transparent message shows up briefly explaining this before fading away.

Comment: His flash app isn't in full screen mode, the browser is full screen and the app is using the full browser size.

Comment: F11 is a WindowsOS specific keyboard shortcut and shouldn't really be relied on for what you are describing.

I imagine that the reason it's not working when the user clicks on the Flash is that Flash is taking focus, the same thing will happen with the scroll-wheel.

My suggestion would be to create a maximise button in your Flash that calls a JavaScript function through ExternalInterface to increase the windows size like this:

window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height);